# MYSQL query consumes too much memory

Tags: mysql

I have a giant MYSQL table and the hostgator shared server I use has 4gb RAM.  I am trying to execute the following query simple using phpmyadmin:

```
DELETE FROM Table1_main where date = '2009-12-31'
```

However, this query just times out because there is insufficient RAM. How can I execute this query without buying a higher performance server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there an index on that column? That's usually the way to speed up a simple query like this.

Here's how to create an index on that column:
`CREATE INDEX ON table1_main (date);`

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this.  How would I create an index on the column.

Comment: I am trying to create an index on the column 'date' only

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: THIS IS A HACK IF you just want it to get it done

I bet there is a better way to do this.

```
  DELETE FROM Table1_main where date = '2009-12-31' limit 1000000
```

try to increase the number until it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MySQL greater than or equal to version 5.1, then you can use partitions.

The other solution would be to use a cycle to delete N records at a time until the total is deleted.

Please take a look at insights on both approaches at:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Hope that helps,